# javascript array-object convert one key, array value single object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object like this:

```
[ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
]
```

I want:

```
{"number": [12, 40], "string": ["hi", "bye"]}
```

Or:

```
{"number": "12,40", "string": "hi,bye"}
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

***Solution With Concatenated String:***

```js
var data = [ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
] 
data = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.number = a.number + ',' +c.number;
  a.string = a.string + ',' +c.string;
  return a;
});
console.log(data);
```

***Solution With Array:***

```js
var data = [ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
]

data = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.number.push(c.number);
  a.string.push(c.string);
  return a;
}, {number:[],string:[]});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this like so:

```
let array = [ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
];

let resultObject = {
    numbers: [],
  strings: []
}

for (let element of array) {
 resultObject.numbers.push(element.number);
 resultObject.strings.push(element.string);
}

console.log(resultObject);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that:

```js
var arr = [ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
];
var res = arr.reduce((acc, item)=>{
  if(acc.number && acc.string){
    acc.number.push(item.number);
    acc.string.push(item.string);
  } else {
    acc = {
      number: [item.number],
      string: [item.string]
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array and the entris of the object and collect all value with their key in an array without having hardcoded properties.

```js
var array = [{ number: 12, string: "hi" }, { number: 40, string: "bye" }],
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, o) => Object.entries(o).reduce(
            (s, [k, v]) => ((s[k] = s[k] || []).push(v), s),
            r
        ),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith) to combine them:

```js
const arr = [{ "number": 12, "string": "hi"}, { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}];

const result =_.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (s = [], o) => [...s, o]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```